# Replace a whole dataframe with another (overwrite) (Python 3.4 pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Updated update:

I did the following and it worked:
1. Replaced if if-elif structure with if-elif-else (see below).
2. evaluated dec as a string (i.e. dec == '1' instead of dec == 1)

```
if len(SframeDup.index) > 0 and dec == '1':
    SframeDup.to_csv('NWEA CSVs/Students/StudentDuplicates.csv', sep=',')
    print ("%d instances of repeated student IDs detected." % len(SframeDup.index))
    print ("See StudentDuplicates.csv for duplicates.")
    print ("\nThis program will now stop.")
    raise SystemExit      

    #quit() and exit() work too, but only in the editor
    #doing this in Ipython Notebook will restart the kernal and require
    #re-running and re-compiling preceeding code
elif len(SframeDup.index) >0  and dec == '2':
    print ("%d instances of repeated student IDs detected." % len(SframeDup.index))
    print ("See StudentDuplicates.csv for duplicates.")
    Sframe['dup_check_1'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = False)
    Sframe['dup_check_2'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = True)
    Sframe = Sframe[(Sframe['dup_check_1'] == False) & (Sframe['dup_check_2'] == False)]
    del Sframe['dup_check_1'], Sframe['dup_check_2']

else:
    print ("No duplicates found. Oh yeah!")
```

Update:

Though I've "moved on" to the best of my ability, I wanted to document this as best as possible. I'm pasting 2 sets of code; the first attempts to use the if-elif but fails to make Sframe get rid of duplicates. The second successfully omits duplicates but to do so, I had to get rid of the if-elif.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import csv
import os
import sys


path = r'NWEA CSVs/Students/Raw'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
Sframe = pd.DataFrame()

list = []
for file in allFiles:
    sdf = pd.read_csv(file,index_col=None, header=0)
    list.append(sdf)
Sframe = pd.concat(list,ignore_index=False)

Sframe.to_csv('NWEA CSVs/Students/OutStudents.csv', sep=',')

Sframe["TermSchoolStudent"]=Sframe["TermName"]+Sframe["SchoolName"]+\
Sframe["StudentID"].map(str)

SframeDup = Sframe[Sframe.duplicated("TermSchoolStudent") == True]


if len(SframeDup.index) > 0:
    SframeDup.to_csv('NWEA CSVs/Students/StudentDuplicates.csv', sep=',')
    print ("%d instances of repeated student IDs detected." % len(SframeDup.index))
    print ("See StudentDuplicates.csv for duplicates.")
    print ("Enter 1 to make corrections and rerun program. \
\nEnter 2 to proceed without repeated student IDs.")
    dec = input("-->")
    if dec == 1:
        print ("This program will now stop.")
        print ("See StudentDuplicates.csv for duplicates.")    
        raise SystemExit


elif dec == 2:


        Sframe['dup_check_1'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = False)
        Sframe['dup_check_2'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = True)
        Sframe = Sframe[(Sframe['dup_check_1'] == False) & (Sframe['dup_check_2'] == False)]
        del Sframe['dup_check_1'], Sframe['dup_check_2']



print (len(Sframe))
```

**Output: 2840**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import csv
import os
import sys

path = r'NWEA CSVs/Students/Raw'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
Sframe = pd.DataFrame()

list = []
for file in allFiles:
    sdf = pd.read_csv(file,index_col=None, header=0)
    list.append(sdf)
Sframe = pd.concat(list,ignore_index=False)

Sframe.to_csv('NWEA CSVs/Students/OutStudents.csv', sep=',')

Sframe["TermSchoolStudent"]=Sframe["TermName"]+Sframe["SchoolName"]+\
Sframe["StudentID"].map(str)

SframeDup = Sframe[Sframe.duplicated("TermSchoolStudent") == True]


if len(SframeDup.index) > 0:
    SframeDup.to_csv('NWEA CSVs/Students/StudentDuplicates.csv', sep=',')
    print ("%d instances of repeated student IDs detected." % len(SframeDup.index))
    print ("See StudentDuplicates.csv for duplicates.")



Sframe['dup_check_1'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = False)
Sframe['dup_check_2'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = True)
Sframe = Sframe[(Sframe['dup_check_1'] == False) & (Sframe['dup_check_2'] == False)]
del Sframe['dup_check_1'], Sframe['dup_check_2']



print (len(Sframe))
```

**Output: 2834**

**

- Old stuff:

**
I have what I think is a simple question with an answer that is not obvious to me as a new programmer. Basically, I have a dataframe (Sframe) and my program checks it for duplicates. If the user indicates that the program should proceed without the duplicates, duplicates (and their unique values) are then removed from the dataframe and Sframe should be made equal to Sframe with the duplicates removed (hence replacing the original Sframe with a modified one). After that, in the main program, if "2" was selected by the user as above, Sframe should be the modified version. Otherwise, if no duplicates were detected in the first place (and the user input was never entered as a result), the original Sframe should be used.

My code looks something like this:

```
Import Pandas as pd
Sframe = pd.DataFrame()
```

Here, the code checks for duplicates. If they exist, then the following runs.
If they do not exist, the following is skipped and Sframe is used as originally defined.

This is the code that assumes duplicates were detected:

```
dec = input("-->")
if dec == 1:
    print ("This program will now stop.")
    print ("this_file.csv to resolve a problem.")    
    raise SystemExit

elif dec == 2:       
    # add "Repeated" field to student with duplicates table. Values="NaN"
    SframeDup["Repeated"]="NaN"

    # New table joins (left, inner) Sframe with duplicates table (SframeDup) to
    # identify all rows of duplicates (including the unique values that had
    # duplicates)
    SframeWDup=pd.merge(Sframe, SframeDup, on='identifier', how='left')
    # Eliminate all repeating rows, including originals as pulled during left join
    SframeWODup=SframeWDup[SframeWDup.Repeated_y!="NaN"]
    # So here, in my mind, I should be able to just do this and the rest of
    # the code should treat replace Sframe with SframeWODup (without the found
    # duplicates)...
    Sframe = SframeWODup
```

But it doesn't work. I know this because when I check `len(Sframe)` after selecting `2` to eliminate duplicates (and their unique, original values), I get the same number as before dealing with the duplicates.

Thanks in advance for any help. If this is unclear, I will be happy to clarify.

Update:
Sframe.Types
TermName              object

DistrictName          object

SchoolName            object

StudentLastName       object

StudentFirstName      object

StudentMI             object

StudentID             object

StudentDateOfBirth    object

StudentEthnicGroup    object

StudentGender         object

Grade                 object

TermSchoolStudent     object

dtype: object

Sframe.head() returns the table in the image at the following link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1cr7dwUpr_JR3d0YzlwLWFwQU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you not just copy the data frame and then call `drop_duplicates() `?

Comment: I tried that at first, but the problem is that it keeps the original values that are duplicated. In my code, if a value has a duplicate, I want to delete that value and its duplicate.

Comment: Can you provide output from the following commands? (before you prompt the user to make a decision)
`Sframe.dtypes`
`Sframe.head()`

Comment: Which field are you using for `identifier` when you merge `Sframe` and `SframeDup`? `StudentID`?

Comment: For the identifier, I am using a concatenation of TermName, SchoolName, and StudentID.

Comment: Wouldn't `SframeWODup=SframeWDup.dropna(how="any")` work if you have successfully marked the correct row with duplicates? This drops any rows that contain a `NaN` value which could be an issue if you have any column data that could be `NaN`, but since I don't know how your data looks I can't say if this is a viable option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Sframe = SframeWODup.copy()`
UPDATE:
Can you use this code to achieve your desired outcome?

```
# Made-up data
Sframe = pd.DataFrame({'TermName': ['Fall', 'Fall', 'Fall', 'Fall'], 
'DistrictName': ['Downtown', 'Downtown', 'Downtown', 'Downtown'], 
'SchoolName': ['Seattle Central', 'Ballard', 'Ballard', 'Ballard'], 
'StudentLastName': ['Doe', 'Doe', 'Doe', 'Doe'], 
'StudentFirstName': ['John', 'Jane', 'Jane', 'Jane'],
'StudentMI': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
'StudentID': ['1234', '9876', '9876', '9876'],
'StudentDateOfBirth': ['2000-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-01', '2001-01-01'],
'StudentEthnicGroup': ['Asian American', 'White', 'White', 'White'],
'StudentGender': ['M', 'F', 'F', 'F'],
'Grade': ['10th', '9th', '9th', '9th'],
'TermSchoolStudent': ['Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z']})

# Remove duplicates based upon StudentID, in-place (i.e., modify object 'Sframe'). 
# UPDATE: I read that you want duplicates completely removed from data frame.
# Sframe.drop_duplicates(cols = ['StudentID'], take_last = False, inplace = True)

Sframe['dup_check_1'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = False)
Sframe['dup_check_2'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = True)
Sframe = Sframe[(Sframe['dup_check_1'] == False) & (Sframe['dup_check_2'] == False)]
del Sframe['dup_check_1'], Sframe['dup_check_2']
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work. I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here because it seems like that should work.

Comment: I think that would work for removing duplicates (assuming no triplicates), but there are actually triplicates (and maybe even quadruplicates for that matter). The main issue that I'm having is that I need to transfer Sframe back to the main code after the conditional statement result if 2 is selected, else if no duplicates exist, have the code simply use Sframe as defined in the first lines of the program.

Comment: @MichaelLance: The code above removes duplicates, triplicates, and I have reason to believe that it would work with n-licates (where n > 3).

Comment: @MichaelLance: After removing the columns used in duplicate checking, the `Sframe` object is the same as before the conditional statement (minus a few possible redundant rows).

Comment: That's what I thought about my original code but for some reason when I check len(Sframe) at the end in the main code, it still has the duplicate values even if the conditional statement applies option 2 to remove duplicates. Maybe I'm missing your point; is there something about the duplicate checking code that you propose that should work differently than what I am doing after the conditional statement is applied? When I check len(SframeWOdup) at the end of the code, it shows that the duplicates are removed.

Comment: Something just occurred to me (apart from trying your approach to eliminating duplicates): I have another if statement before the one I mentioned in my original post, so it's if, if, elif as far as conditionals. Does that matter? Do I need to do something to more explicitly return control to the main program?

Comment: @MichaelLance: So you have something like the following?
`if outer_condition == True:
    if dec == 1:
        # do something
    elif dec == 2:
        # do something`
In general, the stackoverflow community can best help if you share more information with us.

Comment: Yes. I meant to say return Sframe back to the mainext program instead of "control."

Comment: Sorry about that;  I didn't think it made a difference at first. Dually noted.

Comment: Your approach for deleting duplicates works like a charm. I just need to figure out how to pass the dataframe back to the main code but this is definitely helpful.

Comment: @MichaelLance: If you like my answer, please accept it (also, an upvote wouldn't hurt). ;)

Comment: I tried to upvote but my noob status (only 1 rep point) will not allow me. I ended up taking out the if/elif for now and it works perfectly. I really appreciate your effort. If you like, I can send you the complete code with a zip folder of some contrived CSV data.

Comment: regarding the code you suggested (Sframe('dup_check...): I know that is to identify and remove all duplicates and their original, duplicated values, However, I tried to modify this to keep all unique values that do not have duplicates and am having some trouble. I'll start a new question for this in a second.

Comment: related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735618/python-3-4-remove-duplicates-and-their-corresponding-values

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and it worked: 1. Replaced if if-elif structure with if-elif-else (see below). 2. evaluated dec as a string (i.e. dec == '1' instead of dec == 1)

```
if len(SframeDup.index) > 0 and dec == '1':
    SframeDup.to_csv('NWEA CSVs/Students/StudentDuplicates.csv', sep=',')
    print ("%d instances of repeated student IDs detected." % len(SframeDup.index))
    print ("See StudentDuplicates.csv for duplicates.")
    print ("\nThis program will now stop.")
    raise SystemExit      

    #quit() and exit() work too, but only in the editor
    #doing this in Ipython Notebook will restart the kernal and require
    #re-running and re-compiling preceeding code
elif len(SframeDup.index) >0  and dec == '2':
    print ("%d instances of repeated student IDs detected." % len(SframeDup.index))
    print ("See StudentDuplicates.csv for duplicates.")
    Sframe['dup_check_1'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = False)
    Sframe['dup_check_2'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = True)
    Sframe = Sframe[(Sframe['dup_check_1'] == False) & (Sframe['dup_check_2'] == False)]
    del Sframe['dup_check_1'], Sframe['dup_check_2']

else:
    print ("No duplicates found. Oh yeah!")
```