# Python 3.4 Remove duplicates and their corresponding values

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates

I'd like to remove duplicates as well as their corresponding, original values from a dataframe.

Sframe is the name of my dataframe.
The fields on which I want to check for duplicates are 'TermName', 'SchoolName', and 'StudentID'.

Here's an example of what I'm starting with:

```
TermName SchoolName StudentID
14-15   a   1
14-15   a   1
14-15   a   1
14-15   b   2
14-15   b   2
14-15   b   3
14-15   c   4
14-15   c   5
14-15   d   6
14-15   e   7
14-15   f   8
```

Here's what I'm looking for:

```
TermName SchoolName StudentID
    14-15   a   1
    14-15   a   1
    14-15   a   1
    14-15   b   2
    14-15   b   2
```

@Jubbles showed me how to identify and keep only the duplicate and duplicated rows (i.e. the last 6 rows in my first table example above) with this:

```
#unique that are duplicated only column
Sframe['dup_check_1'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = False)
#duplicates only column
Sframe['dup_check_2'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = True)
#remove both from Sframe (df)
Sframe = Sframe[(Sframe['dup_check_1'] == False) & (Sframe['dup_check_2'] == False)]
#delete duplicate checking columns
del Sframe['dup_check_1'], Sframe['dup_check_2']
```

I tried to get the rows excluded by the above code (and not the rows included above) by changing False to True here:

```
Sframe = Sframe[(Sframe['dup_check_1'] == True) & (Sframe['dup_check_2'] == True)]
```

...but it didn't work. It seems like a simple change in code from False to True, but it does not return the correct number of rows (only 6 instead of 354).

Any ideas?

Comment: In what way didn't work?

Comment: It only returned 6 rows instead of 374, which it should have.

Comment: The original table in your question has only 7 rows.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just used that as an example. To be sure, there are 5180 rows excluding duplicates or duplicated values (which I have successfully isolated with the original code mentioned above) and 354 duplicated/duplicate rows.

Comment: Having simple example data in your code is helpful. But then telling us what your code does to some **different** set of data that we can't see is not helpful.

Comment: I agree with @khelwood. You should tell us what your code does in regards to your example data in order to get a better idea what might be going on.

Comment: Sorry about that. Will the edited question suffice? I put comments in the code to explain what is happening per line.

Comment: Doesn't help. Give us some associated input and output.

Comment: Have you tried the code on the sample data that you gave? That way you could see what is actually happening.

Comment: I just did that and my modification of the code (false to true) produced 0 rows. The original code worked as described above (produced last 6 rows).

Comment: It seems like I just need to subtract the rows produced from the original code from the complete dataframe. Sort of like in this posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284409/how-to-subtract-rows-of-one-pandas-data-frame-from-another

Comment: have you tried `Sframe = Sframe[(Sframe.dup_check_1 == True) & (Sframe.dup_check_2 == True)]`?

Comment: Yes, and my only guess as to why that produces 0 rows is that Sframe['dup_check_1'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = False)
and
Sframe['dup_check_2'] = Sframe.duplicated(cols = ['TermName', 'SchoolName', 'StudentID'], take_last = True) somehow exclude unique, non-duplicated rows.

Comment: Yes I believe that the `duplicated` functionality only denotes the duplicate rows and not the unique ones as you stated.

Comment: Could you do `Sframe.drop(Sframe['dup_check_1'])` and `Sframe.drop(Sframe['dup_check_2'])` to drop the indexed duplicate rows?

Comment: I did that already (using & instead of "and") and it worked for that purpose. At this point, I think I just need to know how to take the dataframe that has none of the duplicates or duplicated values (for which the first code above already works), compare it to the whole dataframe, and return what is extra in the dataframe  (which would be the duplicate and duplicated rows).

Comment: And I'm pretty sure I can do it when I get a chance.